# List view select items in custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview, in each row have five button, but I do not know as get focus over each button, someone know ?

Comment: +1 Why newbie down-vote without comment? Why was this a bad question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

Add tag value to that five button in its Xml file like 1,2,3,4,5

```
int rowNo;
int buttonTag;
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            rowNo = position;             // which row is selected...
            buttonTag = v.getTag();      // which button is selected... if 1 then first if 2 then second 

        }

    });
```

I hope this is what you want..